# Are there any way to create duplicated nodes in HTML with shared memory?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, pointers, canvas

**This is not a beginner question**. With that being said, let's start with some context.

#### Context

There are the times we need to create a website with lots of duplicated elements in it. And sometimes, the elements remain exact same looking, even the nested nodes are the exact same. In these cases, this can in theory be optimized by having the elements point to the same memory. Maybe except for the exact positions of the elements that are not shared, allowing the elements to have different positions. Having cloned elements created this way will allow high performance rendering of the elements, because the processing of an element can be reused on the cloned elements.

#### My specific question(s)

Are there any ways to do the cloning as described in the context section above in the current implementation of DOM renderer, and is supported by any major browser? If not, are there any **other technologies** on the web that we may use to improve the rendering regarding duplicated elements? And briefly describe how? **I don't want any code**.

I am thinking about Canvas and the other technologies utilizing it such as ThreeJS together with WASM to create something that supports this. But then I think again, **is replacing the original DOM renderer the only way to achieve this**?

Comment: No. The DOM is comprised of distinct Node objects. A given Node can be in a given DOM exactly once (or not at all).

Comment: use virtual drawing - only elements visible in the viewport. for example you can have a table with 100000 rows but render only visible at a moment. also you can reuse the elements

Comment: There is an `element()` CSS <image> being drafted: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#element-notation but it has lots of unresolved issues.